# mariadb database in phpmyadmin layout

Tags: python-3.x, join, phpmyadmin, mariadb

While working with python3 programming, I installed Phpmyadmin on Debian 11, to verify database was being updated. Somehow, along the way, I got my non-joined tables to become the default values in my base table, Example, the series_id column became the actual series value in the series table. I had not done any join or view setup. I closed Phpmyadmin and when I reopened, it was still showing values from the other table. This database has four tables referenced by "xxxx_id" in four different columns.
Also, the changes in the columns automatically updated the related tables. And the python program used the values instead of the "xxxx_id". I can use view to simulate this, but upon close and open, it is gone 'til I reactivate the view and then it does not automatically update the other tables.
Does anyone know how this happened and how to make it happen in my other databases and tables? It would save my a lot of time and programming if I could do this for my other databases.
I have not been able to reproduce this and adding another column did not get the same effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Anyone using phpmyadmin knows the layout. It involves no code. It is a GUI for Databases.